# Realm using RealmList in RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: realm

i have a model that contains a RealmList of another realm objects and i want to use these objects to be used by my adapter which extends RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter which i used in conjunction with RealmRecyclerView. How do I convert RealmList to RealmResults since constructor of RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter only accepts RealmResults?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `list.where().findAll()`. There is a open issue for letting both both `RealmList` and `RealmResults` implement a shared interface to avoid these kind of problems in the future: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1363

Edit: From Realm 3.0.0, both `RealmResults` and `RealmList` implement the `OrderedRealmCollection` interface, and both support change listeners. So with Realm Android Adapters 2.0.0 or above, there is no need for the above workaround.

Comment: Love finding these little tidbits here and there. This just solved my problem. Thanks!